# Double value changing to zero

Tags: java, mapreduce, double, precision

I am implementing HMM in mapreduce hadoop,but this following section value of bwd goes to zero after double underflow

```
    bwd = new double[numofstates][T];       
                /* initialization (time 0) */
                for (int i = 0; i < numofstates; i++)
                  bwd[i][T-1] = 1;
                /* induction */
                double dtemp ;
                for (int t = T - 2; t >= 0; t--) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < numofstates; i++) {
                        bwd[i][t] = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < numofstates; j++){
                        dtemp = (bwd[j][t+1] * A[i][j] * B[j][o[t+1]]);
                        if(Double.compare(dtemp, 0.0) < 0)
                        {
                           //to check
                            context.write(new Text("t " + t) , new Text("negative"));
                        }
                        else
                            bwd[i][t] =bwd[i][t] + dtemp;
                            //to check

                        context.write(new Text("t "+t + " i "+i + "j "+j),new Text("temp" + dtemp + " " + bwd[i][t]));
                    }
                    }
                  }
```

This is the output :

```
t 108 i 3j 1 temp2.5E-5 5.0E-5
t 108 i 3j 3 temp2.5E-5 1.775E-4
.
.
t 20 i 3 j 2 temp 0.0 0.0
t 21 i 0j 0 temp4.9E-324 4.9E-324
t 21 i 0j 2 temp2.5E-323 3.5E-323
```

now t comes till 21 after that bwd[0][20] also becomes "zero" even that is an addition.I cannot understand what is happening there.

Comment: Values like `3.5E-323` are very close to underflowing to zero. Do you know why you are working with such very small numbers?

Comment: yes that is because of this multiplication (bwd[j][t+1] * A[i][j] * B[j][o[t+1]]) ,just to make code work I patched code with a boolean variable and then assigning a small value to dwd[i][t] but still I don't know how to handle it properly.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Zero is the normal, standard result when you do a calculation whose rounded result would be smaller than the smallest positive double, which is about 4.9E-324. That is a very small number.

Comment: Yeah problem is not that.Thing is that I am summing  bwd[i][t] =bwd[i][t] + dtemp; which initially has some value (see in sample output for t=108 it is 5.0E-5) now further I am adding values to this, now till t = 21 value of d[i][t] is > 0 suddenly it becomes 0.

Comment: Can you construct an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that shows the actual problem, without the confusing tiny numbers?